# Are there any open source JSDoc parser written in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I am looking for a JSDoc parser that I can use in my project.  I am looking for something where I can pass in a JSDoc comment and receive a structured description of what that comment means.  Most of the tools I have seen seem to be able to transform JSDoc comments into HTML or some other format.  I am looking for something that will provide the intermediate representation of a comment that can be used to feed into other tools.

Are there any tools or libraries out there that I can use?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Doctrine project does exactly what I am looking for:

http://eslint.org/doctrine/demo/

Answer (score 1):

If you need only parsing functionality and don't care about tags meaning then [comment-parser](https://github.com/yavorskiy/comment-parser) may help

Answer (score 1):

There is also a dojo project:
https://github.com/wkeese/js-doc-parse

see
http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2013/01/18/generating-and-viewing-custom-api-docs/

it will look like the dojo documentation ( http://dojotoolkit.org/api/ )

Answer (score 0):

what about jsdoc itself ? - with the command line jsdoc yourfile.js -X > parsed.json . With that you have the official thing.